# W/audio_hw_generic: Hardware backing HAL too slow, could only write 0 of 720 frames

Tags: java, android, logcat

In AS logcat I am getting:

```
"W/audio_hw_generic: Hardware backing HAL too slow, could only write 0 of 
720 frames"
```

with

```
"W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 
10090346 , only wrote 9938160
W/InputMethodService: Window size has been changed. This may cause jankiness 
of resizing window: -1 -> -2"
```

Warnings continuously.
What is this warning for? How to recover from it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hardware backing HAL too slow, could only write 0 of 720 frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261188/hardware-backing-hal-too-slow-could-only-write-0-of-720-frames)

Comment: Did you search on StackOverflow before asking this question?