# Hardware backing HAL too slow, could only write 0 of 720 frames

Tags: java, android, logging, android-emulator

Can someone please explain why do I keep getting this warning in android studio all the time? 
It is so annoying as it fills up the entire log and then to search something I have to keep scrolling. Even if I select "show only selected application" still this warning keeps showing.

I am using the default android emulator to test my app.

```
    01-15 15:51:13.304 1338-1361/? W/audio_hw_generic: Hardware backing HAL too slow, could only write 0 of 720 frames
.
. 
.
    01-15 15:51:14.324 1338-1361/? W/audio_hw_generic: Hardware backing HAL too slow, could only write 0 of 720 frames
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the reason and I don't know how to remove it completely but you can select your process (next to the emulator selection) to prevent it from appearing on console.

[image]